# C# & MySQL : Delete Exists

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete column and I keep getting the following error :

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS(DELETE 1 FROM `stock` WHERE `steamId` = 'MyIDGoesHere' AND `stock` =' at line 1

My code :

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE EXISTS(DELETE 1 FROM `" + Main.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseTableName + "` WHERE `steamId` = '" + id + "' AND `stock` = '" + stock + "' LIMIT 1);";
```

Please help me fixing this case. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason that you are deleting the first record only?

Comment: @dana There is only one record now. But yes.

Comment: But in general, would it be OK to delete all records that met the criteria?  If not, then what determines the victim record to delete?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I prefer with first only. But delete all the met the settings also works for now.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you!

Comment: Since you are using MySQL it is easy to just delete the first row so I have added an answer that does this.  This is a bit trickier with SQL Server and i got kind of tripped up since you are using C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would go about deleting the 1st record that met your criteria.  As others have mentioned, it is best to use parameters which I have done as well:

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM `" + Main.Instance.Configuration.Instance.DatabaseTableName + "` WHERE `steamId` = @SteamId AND `stock` = @Stock LIMIT 1;";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SteamId", steamId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", stock);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Works!